# Очистить фон QMainWindow от артефактов при перерисовке изображения

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qgraphicsview

В `QMainWindow` рисую изображение из `QPixmap` в `PaintEvent` следующим образом:

```
painter.begin(self.pixmapHolder)
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight, self.cellPixmap,
                   self.x0, self.y0, self.xe, self.ye)

painter.end()
self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmapHolder)
self.lbl.resize(min(width, self.maxImageWidth), min(height, self.maxImageHeight))
```

Переменные `self.x0` и `self.y0` отвечают за начало прямоугольника, который надо отобразить на изображении, если оно полностью не помещается, а `self.xe` и `self.ye` - его конец.

Получается изображение:

[image]

При перетаскивании изображения остаются следы, как в лагающей winXP:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перетаскивание осуществляется изменением `x0`, `y0`, `xe`, `ye`:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.isDraged and self.isImageLoaded:
        self.isMoving = True
        self.x0 -= event.x() - self.cursorX
        self.y0 -= event.y() - self.cursorY
        self.xe -= event.x() - self.cursorX
        self.ye -= event.y() - self.cursorY

        self.cursorX = event.x()
        self.cursorY = event.y()
```

Насколько я понимаю, проблема именно в очистке "формы". Как можно это реализовать?

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import qRgb
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QBrush, QColor, QImage, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QLabel, QPushButton, QSlider, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from utils.targetbuild import *


class ImageClickEvents(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, screen_width, screen_height, isImageLoaded=False):
        super(ImageClickEvents, self).__init__()
        
        self.isImageLoaded = False
        self.isDrawingRect = False
        self.newRectCoord = None

        self.isDraged = False
        self.isMoving = False
        self.x0 = 0
        self.y0 = 0
        self.xe = screen_width
        self.ye = screen_height
        self.xScaled = 1.0
        # местоположения курсора мыши для drag
        self.cursorX = 0
        self.cursorY = 0

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.cellPixmap = QPixmap(screen_width, screen_height)
        self.cellPixmapUnscaled = QPixmap(screen_width, screen_height)
        self.pixmapHolder = QPixmap(700, 400)

        self.imageWidth = 700
        self.imageHeight = 400
        self.resize(QSize(875, 400))

        # const codes of button in qt
        # here's mouse buttons:
        self.NoneButton = 0x00000000
        self.LeftButton = 0x00000001
        self.RightButton = 0x00000002
        self.AllButtons = 0x07ffffff

        self.initGUI()

    def initGUI(self):
        self.lbl.setGeometry(0, 0, 700, 400)

        openImageBtn = QPushButton('&Открыть изображение', self)
        openImageBtn.setGeometry(720, 100, 130, 25)
        openImageBtn.clicked.connect(self.showOpenFileDialog)

        saveImageBtn = QPushButton('&Сохранить изображение', self)
        saveImageBtn.setGeometry(720, 210, 130, 25)
        saveImageBtn.clicked.connect(self.showSaveFileDialog)

        self.update()
        self.show()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        numPixels = event.pixelDelta()
        numDegrees = event.angleDelta()
        if not numPixels.isNull():
            self.xScaled += 0.1*signum(numPixels.y())
        elif not numDegrees.isNull():
            self.xScaled += 0.1*signum(numDegrees.y())
        if self.xScaled < 0.5:
            self.xScaled = 0.5
        elif self.xScaled >= 10.0:
            self.xScaled = 10.0

        self.lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(1, 1));
        self.cellPixmap = self.cellPixmapUnscaled.scaled(self.xScaled * self.imageWidth,
                               self.xScaled * self.imageHeight,
                               Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        btn = event.button()
        if self.isImageLoaded and btn == self.LeftButton:
            self.isDraged = True
            print(event.x())
            self.cursorX = event.x()
            self.cursorY = event.y()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.isDraged and self.isImageLoaded:
            self.isMoving = True
            self.x0 -= event.x() - self.cursorX
            self.y0 -= event.y() - self.cursorY
            self.xe -= event.x() - self.cursorX
            self.ye -= event.y() - self.cursorY

            self.cursorX = event.x()
            self.cursorY = event.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if not self.isImageLoaded:
            return

        mx, my = QMouseEvent.pos().x(), QMouseEvent.pos().y()
        if mx > 700:
            return

        pressedButton = QMouseEvent.button()

        if not self.isImageLoaded:
            return
        if self.isDraged and self.isMoving:
            self.isDraged = False
            self.isMoving = False
            return
        if not self.isDrawingRect:
            self.isDraged = False

    def showOpenFileDialog(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open image', '.')[0]
        print(file_name)
        if file_name == '':
            return

        self.cellPixmapUnscaled = QPixmap(file_name)
        self.cellPixmap = self.cellPixmapUnscaled.copy()
        self.isImageLoaded = True
        self.x0 = 0
        self.y0 = 0
        self.xe = min(self.cellPixmap.width(), self.imageWidth)
        self.ye = min(self.cellPixmap.height(), self.imageHeight)
        self.xScaled = 1.0

        self.update()

    def showSaveFileDialog(self):
        if not self.isImageLoaded:
            nope = QMessageBox()
            nope.setText("Зарузите избражение")
            nope.exec()
            return

        file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save image', '.')[0]
        if file_name == '':
            return

        if file_name[-4:] != '.png':
            file_name += '.png'
        print(file_name)
        saving_image = QPixmap.toImage(self.cellPixmap)
        saving_image.save(file_name, 'PNG')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.pixmapHolder)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.imageWidth, self.imageHeight, self.cellPixmap,
                           self.x0, self.y0, self.xe, self.ye)
        painter.end()
        if self.isImageLoaded:
            self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmapHolder)
            height = self.cellPixmap.height()
            width = self.cellPixmap.width()
            self.lbl.resize(min(width, self.imageWidth), min(height, self.imageHeight))

            start_x = 0
            start_y = 0
            if width < self.imageWidth:
                start_x = (self.imageWidth - width) / 2
            if height < self.imageHeight:
                start_y = (self.imageHeight - height) / 2

            self.lbl.move(start_x, start_y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    image_click = ImageClickEvents(700, 400, False)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-полный пример для демонстрации вашей проблема.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю вам попробовать вариант без математических расчетов.
Все что вам нужно, так это установить флаг `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable`,
который поддерживает интерактивное движение с помощью мыши. 
Если щелкнуть элемент и перетащить его, элемент будет перемещаться вместе с курсором мыши. 
Если у элемента есть дети, все дети также перемещаются. 
Если элемент является частью выбора, все выбранные элементы также перемещаются. 
Эта функция предоставляется `для удобства благодаря базовой реализации обработчиков событий мыши QGraphicsItem`.

```
import sys                             
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *                           
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.openImageBtn = QPushButton('&Открыть изображение', self)
        self.saveImageBtn = QPushButton('&Сохранить изображение', self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.openImageBtn)
        layout.addWidget(self.saveImageBtn)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self._itemImage = None

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.widget = Widget()
        self.widget.openImageBtn.clicked.connect(self.showOpenFileDialog)
#        self.saveImageBtn.clicked.connect(self.showSaveFileDialog)

        self._scene = QGraphicsScene()         
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self._scene)
        self.showImage('im.png')
        self.view.setScene(self._scene)        

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget)

    def showOpenFileDialog(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                                self, 
                                'Пожалуйста, выберите изображение', 
                                '.',
                                'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)'
                                               )[0]
        if not file_name:
            return
        if self._itemImage:
            # Удалить предыдущий элемент
            self._scene.removeItem(self._itemImage)
            del self._itemImage
        self.showImage(file_name)    

    def showImage(self, file_name):            
        self._itemImage = self._scene.addPixmap(QPixmap(file_name))
        self._itemImage.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)            # <<<=====

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """ Очистите все элементы в сцене, когда окно `закрыто` """
        self._scene.clear()
        self._itemImage = None
        super(MainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(QSize(700, 400))
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, выглядит гораздо приятнее. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы item не перехватывал  wheelEvent? И каким образом лучше рисовать на изображении при действиях пользователя?